# OFBiz mobile commerce (m-commerce)?

Tags: e-commerce, ofbiz

Is there any functionality in OFBiz for m-commerce store? I already used OFBiz for eCommerce store. OFBiz has great functionality for eCommerce. I just want to know is there any way for building m-commerce store with OFBiz functionality or we can just make different design for mobile and maintaining same OFBiz functionality ? I am unable to find any answer to this. Please help me with best way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create a new application, which will be reusing what is existing.

look at hhfacility, it's a simplified interface for facility management for hand held devices.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The mobile application can also use the same application, only the FTL of Presentation layer differs, the backend services will remain same.